# How to add askfont dialog in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, fonts

We can make a Dialog to let the user choose a color in `tkinter` library

```py
tkinter.colorchooser
```

But how to do that for font...
Is there a method?

According to me, there is no apparent method to do that as per the Tkinter Docs. SO how do you make a font chooser dialog box ...?